# What is an infinite limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, epsilon-delta

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = c$$
$$\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = \infty$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \infty$$

When someone says, give a delta epsilon proof of an $\text{infinite limit}$, which do they mean? $c$ is constant.

Comment: Well, I'd call the first one a "limit to infinity", and the second one a divergent limit.  The third would be both in my book.

Comment: An infinite limit could mean both the second and the third. but not the first.
a limit is what on the right side of the equality, c i not infinite. but infinity is infinite!

Comment: Think of the symbol $\infty$ as meaning "as large as you want".

Comment: @YvesDaoust after 4 years

Comment: Glad to see you are still there !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we write $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=c$ we mean

> $$\forall \epsilon>0,\,\exists M>0 \text{ s.t. }  x>M \implies |f(x)-c|<\epsilon$$

meaning that $f$ becomes arbitrarily close to $c$ as $x$ becomes large.

---

When we write $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\infty$ we mean

> $$\forall M>0,\,\exists \delta>0 \text{ s.t. } 0<|x-c|<\delta \implies f(x)>M$$

meaning that $f$ becomes arbitrarily large as $x$ approaches $c$.

---

When we write $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$ we mean

> $$\forall M>0,\,\exists N>0 \text{ s.t. } x>N \implies f(x)>M$$

meaning that $f$ becomes arbitrarily large as $x$ becomes large.